# Is there a method to check if a portion of text inside a xlsx cell is bold?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

Using openpyxl we can properly check if a cell is fully bold/not bold, but we cannot work with richtext so having two words, one bolded and one not, will make the check fail.

This can be done correctly with xlrd, but it doesn't support xlsx files. Converting from xlsx to xls is risky, especially in my use case, since I have a big file with many languages and I think i could lose information.

How can I check if cells substrings are bold inside a xlsx file?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: not yet, but upcoming **openpyxl v3.1** will be able to satisfy your request.

---

I took a quick tour through the late 2022 state of python-excel affair with respect to this very feature, which relies on being able to manage **Rich Text** objects as cell contents:

- **pylightxl** was new to me, so I quickly browsed the project for a bit. But as the name indicates, it is geared towards a small, maintainable feature set. Only cell values are in scope, formatting is intentionally skipped.
- **xlrd** supports rich text, though only legacy `.xls`, as you pointed out in your question already.
- **xlsxwriter** luckily is able to construct cells containing rich text with mixed formatting ([example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html)), but unfortunately only deals with writing files.
- **openpyxl** finally currently does not support rich text... but: with the upcoming release 3.1, it will, thanks to [merge request !409](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/merge_requests/409) that was completed earlier this year.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know when can we expect the new release to be published?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find a roadmap/milestone plan in the project. So I fear we must wait for the day "when it's done". In the meantime, you could try experimenting with using a development version (i.e. installing from the repo's main branch), but I would not rely on such a state for anything productive.

Answer (score 0):

example, using `openpyxl 3.0.10`:
have this sample:
[image]
then use:

```
import openpyxl
test_file = "test_spreadsheet.xlsx"

obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(test_file)
sheet_ref = obj.active



cell1 = sheet_ref.cell(row = 3, column = 2)
cell_font1 = cell1.font
print(cell_font1.b)
cell = sheet_ref.cell(row = 4, column = 2)
cell_font = cell.font
print(cell_font.b)
```

result:

```
$ python test.py
False
True
```

so you could build it yourself:

```
def is_text_in_cell_bold(cell_obj):
    if (cell_obj.font.b):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: That's only checking whether the whole cell is bold. OP was asking about a cell _[with **partially bold** text in it]_.