# Is there a way to detect the formatting (bold, italic, underline) of a rich text in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, formatting, openpyxl, markup

I am quite new to programming and I need to convert excel files to csv while keeping a track of the formatting of the text in the excel file. Ex: column_name = "book description". cell :"The book *Book*, author **Author** dates back to *date*". I was thinking of rewriting the excel file to a new file and adding the HTML tags <em>Book</em>, <b>Author</b> to have a record of the formatting information in the csv file. I only managed to detect the font of the cell where all the text is formatted. However, I could not detect formatting for cells that have combination of simple text and formatted text. I tried installing openpyxl version 3.1.2, which seems to offer the possibility to handle rich text (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html), but I failed installing this version of the package. Did anyone managed to install it and if yes, were you able to detect rich text with both unformatted and formatted words in Excel ? Or is there another way of doing this ? Thank you.

This is a basic code using openpyxl. The rich_text option does not work for me.
`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xslx")
ws = wb.active

text = []

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        text.append(cell.value)
        if cell.font.bold:
            cell.value = f'<b>{cell.value}</b>'
        if cell.font.italic:
            cell.value = f'<em>{cell.value}</em>
wb.save("modified_file.xslx")
```

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363374/is-there-a-method-to-check-if-a-portion-of-text-inside-a-xlsx-cell-is-bold

Comment: Pull Request PR409 Support for Rich Text in cells https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/merge_requests/409/. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html

Comment: What do you mean "does not work for you"?

Comment: @CharlieClark, it actually worked in the end! I managed to install it today. I got some errors the other days and I thought it was because of the python version I am currently using (3.8 version).

Comment: Openpyxl works fine with Python 3.8 The only thing you need for RichText support is lxml.